# redhawk install process modifies /dev/* to usrp:usrp

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I recently installed redhawk on RHEL 5.8 using the instructions found here http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch2.html#x4-60002

I was installing from the redhawk-yum-1.10.0-10-el5-x86_64.tar.gz  file.

After the installation and a reboot I found that all the files in /dev/ on the system had been changed to be owned by usrp:usrp and permissions were changed so that other users could not write to those files.
This created a lot of problems as many user scripts on the system write things to /dev/null which became unavailable.

Has anyone seen this before?

I also noticed that all the directories like /usr/local/redhawk were owned by root:root instead of redhawk:redhawk.

UPDATE: 
I found that even after restoring the correct ownership and permissions to /dev/* files a reboot reverted those changes. Then I removed the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usrp-udh.rules` and restored the correct permissions once more. After a reboot this time, the correct permissions persisted and the problem ended. Something must be up with the USRP-UDH rules installed by the UDH RPM with redhawk in EL5 series installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that the problem is being caused by the udev rules file installed by the UHD RPM. Specifically, The udev system within CentOS5 (14.32.el5) does not support the SUBSYSTEMS and ATTRS tags, which are included in the udev rules file created using the official UHD driver and fedora spec file. Since the current version of REDHAWK (1.10.1) does not support CentOS5, the recommended solution is to upgrade to CentOS6. If this is not a viable option for you, you'll need to obtain a CentOS5-compatible build of the UHD drivers.